# Representing asn structs in c++

Tags: c++, asn.1

I have an asn schema file and am having trouble in representing two types of data

1. `id TID`
   where `TID::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(4))`

How do I set the value of `id`? If it was type `INTEGER`, we directly set `id = 10` for example.

2. `objects List`
   where `List::= SEQUENCE (SIZE(1..256)) OF Data` ,

> ```
> Data::= SEQUENCE {
>     cl1 objData1,
>     cl2 objData2
>     }
> ```

,

```
objData1::= SEQUENCE {
    cl3 objData3,
    cl4 objData4,
    }
```

My question here is when I am referencing the variables inside the struct created corresponding to `objects`, how do I do that? For example in simpler cases, `refPos Position3D` with

```
Position ::= SEQUENCE {
    lat        Latitude,                
    Long       Longitude
    }
```

the `lat` and `long` can be accessed by `refPos.lat` and `refPos.Long`. But as `data` is a `List` which is a sequence of size 256, and each of those 256 items will have a `objData1` and `objData2`. Is there an indexing involved? So that accessing the `latitude` of the 1st item in the list is done as `objects[1].cl1.cl3.lat` ?

Comment: `How do I set the value of id?` That's not C++, you can set it however you want in whatever abstraction you choose to use. `If it was type INTEGER, we directly set id = 10 ` There is no `INTEGER` in C++. If it would be C++ and if it would be an `int`, then you could do `id = 10`. But the same way if it would be c++ and if it would be an `std::string`, then you would `id = "stri"`. It's unclear to me what are you asking.

Comment: `when I am referencing the variables inside the struct created corresponding to objects, how do I do that?` You "reference" in what? In English, you can just say that you mean an object list. In C++, you have to first write it in C++.... `the lat and long can be accessed by refPos.lat and refPos.Long` In what language? `Position ::=` is not C++, you can't access it in C++.

Comment: @KamilCuk I use the asn tool to generate the c++ header and source files corresponding to the schema. Then I use these files to create a packet using c++ and th epacket will have members like `packet->id`, `packet->objects`

Comment: `the asn tool` what asn tool? See that "asn tool" documentation and source code it generates.

Comment: https://github.com/vlm/asn1c we provide an schema as an input and it generates the correspding c files

Comment: So inspect `the correspding c files` and see what the specific tool generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

If you look at the code generated by Lev Walkin's asn1c compiler, you'll find that your TID comes out as a containing a pointer to an array of uint8_t, and a length. Allocate an array 4 long, fill in the bytes as you require, and set the length to 4.

Because you've defined it as an OCTET STRING (SIZE(4)), how you initialise it to "10" rather depends. You fill the bytes as 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a. Or equally, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

What I think is that, really, you do want TID to be an integer, 4 bytes long. In which case you'd be better off defining is an INTEGER (0..4294967295). That'll get rendered / generated as a uint32_t on any platform (except Java), and you'd just assign 10 to it in your code.

The reason it'd be better to do that if TID really was supposed to be an integer value is that you then remove any endianness ambiguity. An OCTET STRING (SIZE(4)) used to imitate an integer is ambiguous.

2.

The List gets generated as a structure that contains an pointer to an array of pointers, a count, an allocated size, and a function that can be used to free objects in the list. You have to allocate an array of pointers Data* 256 long, and then allocate individual Data's and put them into that array. The array is indexable:

```
List list;

//allocate array in list
//allocate a Data, put the pointer to it into list.array at some index

// populate the latest entry
list.array[i]->cl1 = ...

// set the length fields
```